# Run Apache http, Apache tomcat and nodejs on same port

Tags: tomcat, httpd, mod-proxy, node.js

I'm a web developer and for a project I need to run tomcat and nodejs without using port.

I've seen some posts about proxy module in httpd, so I've created two virtual hosts as follow :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName localhost
       # ErrorLog "logs/tomcat-error.log"
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /tomcat http://localhost:8080/
       ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      # ErrorLog "logs/nodejs-error.log"
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass /nodejs http://localhost:8000/
      ProxyPassReverse /nodejs http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I try to access both localhost/nodejs or localhost/tomcat I get a Not Found error.

Can someone explain me why ?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by doing this in `sites-enabled` conf :

```
NameVirtualHost MY-IP:80

<VirtualHost MY-IP:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    ServerName dummy.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost MY-IP:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName dummy.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it could help some others guy

Answer (score 0):

The first matched `VirtualHost` shadows the followings. So the `ProxyPass` to `nodejs` is never reached.

You should merge it all as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   # ErrorLog "logs/tomcat-error.log"

   <Location /tomcat/ >
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
   </Location>

   # ErrorLog "logs/nodejs-error.log"
   <Location /nodejs/ >
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Have you enabled the `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules?

And of course the tomcat and nodejs side should be in-place.

Comment: I work on windows. How can I have default ```proxy.conf``` file ?

Comment: Cause, for now I obtain a 404 Not Found when i try to access ```http://localhost/tomcat``` even if ```http://localhost:8080/``` is up

Comment: I edited answer to add a trailing slash. Would you try to edit your vhost and connect to `http://localhost/tomcat/` ?

Comment: Not working ... Where can I write proxy config ?

Comment: Actual config : ```LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so```
```LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so```
```#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so```

Comment: Can you post your apache2 error logs after connecting to: `http://localhost/tomcat/`? Adding slashes makes any difference?

Comment: The error logs does not contain any error relative to ```/tomcat/``` route.